# How to position elements center vertically with float element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have got the floating image and its descriptions.
I want `divs` which contain descriptions to be positioned center vertically and flow around the image.
Here is my code.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.parent:after, .parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.left-child {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  border: 1px red solid;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child"></div>
  <div clss="right-child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div clss="right-child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div clss="right-child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
</div>
```

Anybody who can help me with solving this?

Comment: you mean right-child should be vertically centered?

Comment: yeah, right. and I want `right-child` elements to flow around the `left-child` element.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you flex box.

A good link about that is here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.left-child {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child"></div>
  <div class="right-child">
    Insert your centered stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want `right-child` elements to flow around the `left-child` element.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `parent` display property to `table` and the child to `table-cell` the you can use the `vertical-align` property to align you content vertically center on its parent:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:after, .parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.left-child {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  border: 1px red solid;
  float: left;
}

.right-child {
  display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child"></div>
  <div class="right-child">
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>  
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want `right-child` elements to flow around the `left-child` element.

Comment: Hmm. Do you maybee mean that the right side must be centered horizontally? Or can you paint it, or share a screenshot of an example?

Comment: If the total height of the `right-child` elements is smaller than the `left-child` element, the `right-child` elements should be centered vertically, and if greater, they flow around the `left-child` element. @DanielMichelfelder make sense?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve that with CSS. I think you must mix css with javascript. Check in javascript if the height of the right container is greater that the left container. If it is the case use float. if not use flex box